# how to make page stop scrolling when lightbox is active when I give the lightbox close absolute position

Tags: php, html, css, photoshop

I'm using the below `html` code, but not able to prevent the `lightbox overlay` scroll off, when click on `image`.

```
<div class="grid_area_image">    <a class="example-image-link" href="Images/Vegetation distribution.png" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."> <img src="Images/Vegetation distribution.png" alt="Vegetation distribution" class="img-responsive example-image"></a>    </div>
```

so please tell me how to do it .. here is the lightbox-min.js

```
 /*!
 * Lightbox v2.8.2
 * by Lokesh Dhakar
 *
 * More info:
 * http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
 *
 * Copyright 2007, 2015 Lokesh Dhakar
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/LICENSE
 */
!function(a,b){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],b):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=b(require("jquery")):a.lightbox=b(a.jQuery)}(this,function(a){function b(b){this.album=[],this.currentImageIndex=void 0,this.init(),this.options=a.extend({},this.constructor.defaults),this.option(b)}return b.defaults={albumLabel:"Image %1 of %2",alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices:!1,fadeDuration:500,fitImagesInViewport:!0,positionFromTop:50,resizeDuration:700,showImageNumberLabel:!0,wrapAround:!1,disableScrolling:!1},b.prototype.option=function(b){a.extend(this.options,b)},b.prototype.imageCountLabel=function(a,b){return this.options.albumLabel.replace(/%1/g,a).replace(/%2/g,b)},b.prototype.init=function(){this.enable(),this.build()},b.prototype.enable=function(){var b=this;a("body").on("click","a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]",function(c){return b.start(a(c.currentTarget)),!1})},b.prototype.build=function(){var b=this;a('').appendTo(a("body")),this.$lightbox=a("#lightbox"),this.$overlay=a("#lightboxOverlay"),this.$outerContainer=this.$lightbox.find(".lb-outerContainer"),this.$container=this.$lightbox.find(".lb-container"),this.containerTopPadding=parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-top"),10),this.containerRightPadding=parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-right"),10),this.containerBottomPadding=parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-bottom"),10),this.containerLeftPadding=parseInt(this.$container.css("padding-left"),10),this.$overlay.hide().on("click",function(){return b.end(),!1}),this.$lightbox.hide().on("click",function(c){return"lightbox"===a(c.target).attr("id")&&b.end(),!1}),this.$outerContainer.on("click",function(c){return"lightbox"===a(c.target).attr("id")&&b.end(),!1}),this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev").on("click",function(){return 0===b.currentImageIndex?b.changeImage(b.album.length-1):b.changeImage(b.currentImageIndex-1),!1}),this.$lightbox.find(".lb-next").on("click",function(){return b.currentImageIndex===b.album.length-1?b.changeImage(0):b.changeImage(b.currentImageIndex+1),!1}),this.$lightbox.find(".lb-loader, .lb-close").on("click",function(){return b.end(),!1})},b.prototype.start=function(b){function c(a){d.album.push({link:a.attr("href"),title:a.attr("data-title")||a.attr("title")})}var d=this,e=a(window);e.on("resize",a.proxy(this.sizeOverlay,this)),a("select, object, embed").css({visibility:"hidden"}),this.sizeOverlay(),this.album=[];var f,g=0,h=b.attr("data-lightbox");if(h){f=a(b.prop("tagName")+'[data-lightbox="'+h+'"]');for(var i=0;ij||e.height>i)&&(e.width/j>e.height/i?(h=j,g=parseInt(e.height/(e.width/h),10),d.width(h),d.height(g)):(g=i,h=parseInt(e.width/(e.height/g),10),d.width(h),d.height(g)))),c.sizeContainer(d.width(),d.height())},e.src=this.album[b].link,this.currentImageIndex=b},b.prototype.sizeOverlay=function(){this.$overlay.width(a(document).width()).height(a(document).height())},b.prototype.sizeContainer=function(a,b){function c(){d.$lightbox.find(".lb-dataContainer").width(g),d.$lightbox.find(".lb-prevLink").height(h),d.$lightbox.find(".lb-nextLink").height(h),d.showImage()}var d=this,e=this.$outerContainer.outerWidth(),f=this.$outerContainer.outerHeight(),g=a+this.containerLeftPadding+this.containerRightPadding,h=b+this.containerTopPadding+this.containerBottomPadding;e!==g||f!==h?this.$outerContainer.animate({width:g,height:h},this.options.resizeDuration,"swing",function(){c()}):c()},b.prototype.showImage=function(){this.$lightbox.find(".lb-loader").stop(!0).hide(),this.$lightbox.find(".lb-image").fadeIn("slow"),this.updateNav(),this.updateDetails(),this.preloadNeighboringImages(),this.enableKeyboardNav()},b.prototype.updateNav=function(){var a=!1;try{document.createEvent("TouchEvent"),a=this.options.alwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices?!0:!1}catch(b){}this.$lightbox.find(".lb-nav").show(),this.album.length>1&&(this.options.wrapAround?(a&&this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev, .lb-next").css("opacity","1"),this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev, .lb-next").show()):(this.currentImageIndex>0&&(this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev").show(),a&&this.$lightbox.find(".lb-prev").css("opacity","1")),this.currentImageIndex1&&this.options.showImageNumberLabel){var c=this.imageCountLabel(this.currentImageIndex+1,this.album.length);this.$lightbox.find(".lb-number").text(c).fadeIn("fast")}else this.$lightbox.find(".lb-number").hide();this.$outerContainer.removeClass("animating"),this.$lightbox.find(".lb-dataContainer").fadeIn(this.options.resizeDuration,function(){return b.sizeOverlay()})},b.prototype.preloadNeighboringImages=function(){if(this.album.length>this.currentImageIndex+1){var a=new Image;a.src=this.album[this.currentImageIndex+1].link}if(this.currentImageIndex>0){var b=new Image;b.src=this.album[this.currentImageIndex-1].link}},b.prototype.enableKeyboardNav=function(){a(document).on("keyup.keyboard",a.proxy(this.keyboardAction,this))},b.prototype.disableKeyboardNav=function(){a(document).off(".keyboard")},b.prototype.keyboardAction=function(a){var b=27,c=37,d=39,e=a.keyCode,f=String.fromCharCode(e).toLowerCase();e===b||f.match(/x|o|c/)?this.end():"p"===f||e===c?0!==this.currentImageIndex?this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex-1):this.options.wrapAround&&this.album.length>1&&this.changeImage(this.album.length-1):("n"===f||e===d)&&(this.currentImageIndex!==this.album.length-1?this.changeImage(this.currentImageIndex+1):this.options.wrapAround&&this.album.length>1&&this.changeImage(0))},b.prototype.end=function(){this.disableKeyboardNav(),a(window).off("resize",this.sizeOverlay),this.$lightbox.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration),this.$overlay.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration),a("select, object, embed").css({visibility:"visible"}),this.options.disableScrolling&&a("body").removeClass("lb-disable-scrolling")},new b});
//# sourceMappingURL=lightbox.min.map
```

Comment: You don't have to post the plugin codes... show your codes.

Comment: see my answer and remove plugin code from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add `disableScrolling: ture` by default is `false` see  [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options)

```
lightbox.option({
   disableScrolling:true
})
```